# how do i minimise the use of else if statements?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I set the value of direction without having to go throw every other option?

```
if (Input.GetKey(right_button)) { direction = 1; }
else if(Input.GetKey(left_button)) { direction = -1; }        
else { direction = 0; }
if (direction!=0) { rb.velocity = new Vector2(player_speed*direction, rb.velocity.y);  }
```

I need to translate player input to movement. I can't use axes because I can't modify them as easily as using this method.

How can I optimize this piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to write the above without if/else would be the following:

```
direction = Input.GetKey(right_button) 
                ? 1
                : Input.GetKey(left_button)
                      ? -1 
                      : 0;
```

I don't know if this is more readable. In this case, I think that this is rather a preference on how you want to write this piece of code than being more readable for sure. In other words, I don't think that the if/else statements are not readable - as a slight modification I would suggest you place in another line the body and not in the same line - but this is again a personal preference :).

```
if (Input.GetKey(right_button)) 
{ 
    direction = 1; 
}
else if(Input.GetKey(left_button)) 
{ 
    direction = -1; 
}
else 
{ 
    direction = 0; 
}
```

Regarding your second question, there isn't any performance issue in your code.

Another approach it would be the following:

```
// set the value of 0 to direction from the start and change it if it is needed
direction = 0;
if (Input.GetKey(right_button)) 
{ 
    direction = 1; 
}
if(Input.GetKey(left_button)) 
{ 
    direction = -1; 
}
```

Essentially we set the value of `direction` to be 0 from the start and we re-set the value only if it is needed (either `Input.GetKey(right_button)` or `Input.GetKey(left_button)` returns true).

Comment: Personally, I would use the third approach but with `direction += 1` and `direction -= 1` so that if both keys are down then the resultant direction is still zeroed.

Answer (score 0):

Your worry about optimization is pre-mature. The answer from @Christos is the best in terms of performance (copied below)

```
// set the value of 0 to direction from the start and change it if it is needed
direction = 0;
if (Input.GetKey(right_button)) 
{ 
    direction = 1; 
}
if(Input.GetKey(left_button)) 
{ 
    direction = -1; 
}
```

This is the only optimization as it removes a branch from the code path.

I would say for style and readability, stay away from the terinary operators (using the bool ? 1 : 0  syntax). They commonly lead to more confusing code for anything past returning a clearly readable value with a clear condition.

The thing to consider in these different implementations is if you want your character to only move four directions (assuming you might add up and down) or support diagonal movement. Removing the 'else' statements in your code will make it so you can move diagonally. If you keep the 'else if', then you will only be able to move in cardinal directions.
If you only want to move left and right, it'd be something to consider what to happen when both are pressed. Does the player go no where? Does the player move in the direction of the last pressed? If you add up and down, how do you keep track if 3 buttons are being pressed?

Answer (score -1):

You can define a collection that determines which inputs provide which direction:

```
var directionMap = new List<(bool isInputPressed, int directionalValue)>
{
    (Input.GetKey(right_button), 1),
    (Input.GetKey(left_button), -1)
};
```

And then to get the direction, you simply get the `directionalValue` from the records in the collection where `isInputPressed` is true:

```
var direction = directionMap.Where(x => x.isInputPressed).Sum(x => x.directionalValue);
```

Using `.Where()` here could potentially produce unexpected results if somehow both buttons are pressed at once. If that is never expected to happen, you could change the above to use `.SingleOrDefault()` instead:

```
var direction = directionMap.SingleOrDefault(x => x.isInputPressed).directionalValue;
```

Note that this will produce an exception if more than one button is being pressed at once. You could either handle this exception in a try/catch block. Or you could verify that only one is being pressed before calling the `.SingleOrDefault()` and then proceed accordingly.

Comment: Your left-hand values are evaluated only at the time of adding them to the list, so they never change.  Perhaps you meant to store delegates, eg. `Func<bool>` ?

Comment: Potentially. If the list is initialized every time that the direction is calculated, then this approach would work fine. Without knowing more context of how this code is being executed, saying that the values within the list need to change is just an assumption.

Comment: We know the left-hand values in the list need to change, it's a poll for user input which could change in any `Update()`! (You'll note the Unity tag on the OP :)  Which means the list would have to be regenerated and re-parsed every frame.

Comment: In that case then, as you said, every execution of Update() would create a new instance of the list with new values. Meaning that the values in each instance of the list would not need to change, and would be safe to be evaluated at the time of the list initialization. Sorry if I'm being dense, I just don't see the issue.

Comment: The technical term is 'over-engineering'.  If it's being recreated every frame (and destroyed every frame, so also a ton of extra GC work), the main issue is one of optimisation. You're creating a fixed-element list then iterating over it to test its values, why not just test its values directly and save on all the list handling?

Comment: Because it provides a solution to OPs question: "how do I minimise the use of else if statements?". Nowhere in the original question is performance mentioned as a concern.